# PL SQL function is created however is not retrived in all_objects list

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, prepared-statement

I have saved and compiled a new function on Oracle database. The new function can be accessed in Oracle PL/SQL Developer IDE, on Functions list or can be found via Database object search option from the same IDE (.). However if I search after it with select:

```
     SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = <Schema name under which I have created the function> AND object_name='FUNCTION NAME'
--- or 

     SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE object_name='FUNCTION NAME'
```

no result is returned.

I need that a non empty result to be returned due to the fact that I will use it in the format . in a Java PreparedCall statement.

What I'm doing wrong, missing?

Comment: check in DBA_OBJECTS as well. use function name in uppercase.

Comment: You might also try `select * from all_objects where owner = 'MY_SCHEMA' and object_type = 'FUNCTION'` to make sure you don't have a lowercase function identifier or something.

Comment: yes Kauschik I can see it under DBA_OBJECTS :-) Thank you :-)

Comment: I don't ever use the value for object_name with lower case. Thank you :-)

Comment: Could you add the Java code you are using to execute the queries ?

Comment: select * from all_objects where owner = 'SCHEMA NAME' and object_type = 'FUNCTION NAME'

Comment: Kaushik helped me with his answer. I have to document myself why is returnded by DBA_OBJECTS and not by ALL_OBJECTS.

Comment: If you're not seeing it in the ALL_* tables, but you are in the DBA_* tables, then that indicates your user doesn't have execute privileges on that function. The ALL_* tables show things that you have privileges for, whereas DBA_* tables show everything. (And USER_* tables show things owned by the schema.)

Comment: Can you please tell me what grant statement can be used to allow the user to have execute rights on a function. Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Found it: GRANT EXECUTE ON Function_name TO Schema_name

Comment: Thank, thank you very much guys :-)